# UI router state not loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have configured some basic state pretty much as it should but it seems the template is not injecting in `<div ui-view></div>`.

Here's my code.

https://plnkr.co/edit/LaMMc8JpCuq09Dav7CFW

**EDIT:**

My Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="crudMasters">

  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="1.0.0-beta.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.0-beta.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <div ui-view></div>

</body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('crudMasters', ['ui.router']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouteProvider){


 $urlRouteProvider.otherwise('/');

  $stateProvider
    .state('root',{
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: "home.htm"
    })
    .state('root.master1', {
      url: '/master1',
      templateUrl: "master1.htm",
      controller: 'master1Ctrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl'
    })
    .state('root.master2', {
      url: '/master2',
      templateUrl: "master2.htm",
      controller: 'master2Ctrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl'
    })
})
app.controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl);


function mainCtrl(){
  let ctrl = this;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many issues with your code,

(i) It's not `urlRouteProvider` it is `$urlRouterProvider`

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/");
  $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: "home.html",
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'

    })
    .state('root.master1', {
      url: '/master1',
      templateUrl: "master1.html",
      controller: 'master1Ctrl'

    })
    .state('root.master2', {
      url: '/master2',
      templateUrl: "master2.html",
      controller: 'master2Ctrl'
    })
})
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/QSsofWQLRYpQg975PmPD?p=preview)**

Comment: I am not quite sure if I get your first line. It is $urlRouteProvider in my code as well.

Comment: it is router not route

Comment: check the demo attached

Comment: Oops ! that was the issue infact. "R" is it is

Comment: Why would you use when instead of otherwise?

Comment: @MegaRacer when is used when you are using ngRoute , i.e angular router

Comment: Exactly. Just was confused by your statement of `many issues`. Though not considered an issue, just wanted to clarify if I missed out on any of the best practices. But seems I'm doing alright considering I used ui-router and not ngRoute.Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

**1)** The main issue of your code is your first route,

```
.state('root',{
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: "home.htm"
})
```

Should be,

```
.state('root',{
    url: '',
    templateUrl: "home.htm"
})
```

This should has the url as '' if you are not on '/' url.

**2)** Also, as @Sajeetharan mentioned, **`$urlRouteProvider`, should be `$urlRouterProvider`.**

check this plunker now, with the same code as yours and with these two changes

[**Working DEMO with your code**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Aebyu7fUkIXyDOe6eP6Y?p=preview)

**So, make those two changes and your plunker is good to go.**

Comment: @Megaracer, Sajeetharan spotted out one of your issues, you also have another issue with your route, I changed that. just check it. no need to even use when here,

Comment: i have actually mentioned both the issues with the code,even though it is not in the answer. This answer is almost the same

Comment: I didn't said you are wrong, I think its better to avoid `when` with `ui-router`

Comment: bro i never mentioned that you said my answer is wrong, my point is your answer is not necessary